# How do I display text in a Pygal map?

Tags: python, string, integer, pygal

My problem here is that I want to display a little bit of text when you click on each country, such as the Capital City of each one. For now, I have just included placeholder numbers. I tried using the str("x") command, but no success was found. What do I do here?

Here is a screenshot of what I currently have, and in the solution I want, I want "Washington DC" to be displayed in place of 66.
[Here is the image result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ7d4.png)

```
# import pygal library
import pygal
mm = pygal.maps.world.World()
# create a world map
worldmap = pygal.maps.world.World()
# set the title of the map
worldmap.title = 'Countries'
# adding the countries
worldmap.add('Random Data', {
        'aq' : 69,
        'cd' : 30,
        'de' : 40,
        'eg' : 50,
        'ga' : 45,
        'hk' : 23,
        'in' : 0,
        'jp' : 65,
        'nz' : 41,  
        'kz' : 32,
        'us' : 66
})
# save into the file
worldmap.render_to_file('worldmapresult.svg')
open('worldmapresult.svg')
print("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tooltip_...` from pygal! [Here](https://www.pygal.org/en/3.0.0/documentation/configuration/tooltip.html) are the documentations for everything tooltip-related.

Add a font size and border radius for the tooltips:

```
worldmap.tooltip_font_size = 14
worldmap.tooltip_border_radius = 10
```

Now add the appropriate labels:

```
worldmap.value_formatter = lambda x: {
    'aq': '', # does it have a capital?
    'cd': 'Kinshasa',
    'de': 'Berlin',
    'eg': 'Cairo',
    'ga': 'Libreville',
    'hk': 'Hong Kong',
    'in': 'New Delhi',
    'jp': 'Tokyo',
    'nz': 'Wellington',
    'kz': 'Astana',
    'us': 'Washington DC'
}[x]
```

Here is the full code:

```
# import pygal library
import pygal

# create a world map
worldmap = pygal.maps.world.World()

# set the title of the map
worldmap.title = 'Countries'

worldmap.tooltip_font_size = 14
worldmap.tooltip_border_radius = 10

worldmap.value_formatter = lambda x: {
    'aq': '',
    'cd': 'Kinshasa',
    'de': 'Berlin',
    'eg': 'Cairo',
    'ga': 'Libreville',
    'hk': 'Hong Kong',
    'in': 'New Delhi',
    'jp': 'Tokyo',
    'nz': 'Wellington',
    'kz': 'Astana',
    'us': 'Washington DC'
}[x]

# adding the countries
worldmap.add('Random Data', {
        'aq' : 69,
        'cd' : 30,
        'de' : 40,
        'eg' : 50,
        'ga' : 45,
        'hk' : 23,
        'in' : 0,
        'jp' : 65,
        'nz' : 41,  
        'kz' : 32,
        'us' : 66
})

# save into the file
worldmap.render_to_file('worldmapresult.svg')
open('worldmapresult.svg')
print("Success")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! Unfortunately, I run into an error. As I run the code, my terminal runs a lot of code, but eventually provides me with result of 
File "c:\users\drapal\programs\onlinesolution.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    worldmap.value_formatter = lambda x: {

KeyError: 69 

I am pretty sure that 69 is referring to Antartica, but I am not sure.. I also do not understand what lambda is referring to! I have read the Documentation, but they have only a few mentions of lambda.

Comment: No, the problem is that you need to fill in the value for 'aq'! :) I don't know the capital - do you? Just replace `''` it with `'Some City in Antarctica'` and it will work! Currently it means that you are trying a non-existing key (which currently is '')!

Comment: Hello, I just went and filled it out, it still does not work! The same error is popping up, and even if i completely remove antarctica in both worldmap formatter and the worldmap add section, the same error is coming.  I am so confused.. also, what is the function of [x] on line 25? I am sorry to keep bringing this up but I am simply so confused, nothing is wokring :c